# Raise a matrix to a fractional power

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to achieve A^k in R with further assumption that k is not an integer (and possibly less than 1).
It seems like `%^%` command does not do the right job. Namely -- `A %^% (1.3) == A %^% 1` while using this command.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're talking about the `%^%` operator from the `expm` package:

> Compute the k-th power of a matrix. Whereas ‘x^k’ computes
>   *element wise* powers, ‘x %^% k’ corresponds to k - 1 matrix
>   multiplications, ‘x %*% x %*% ... %*% x’.

Note the definition of `k`:

> k: an integer, k >= 0.

I believe that if you want fractional powers you can do something like:

```
z <- matrix(c(3,1,1,3),2,2)
expm(1.3*logm(z))
## Note ...

##              [,1]     [,2]
##     [1,] 4.262578 1.800289
##     [2,] 1.800289 4.262578
```

I think this may only work for positive-definite matrices, though.

Comment: Your mind reading skills are indeed impressive. This one was even more confusing as OP asked for `k` smaller than 1... I guess `%^%` was the clue, though I never saw this operator before.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is still relevant to you, and as already pointed out, my own package called 'powerplus' has a function called 'Matpow' that enables you to raise any diagonalizable matrix to any power (even complex powers after the recent update).
Edit: Version 3.0 extends capabilities to (some) non-diagonalizable matrices too.

Answer (score 0):

This morning I had the same problem (unfortunately logm only works for matrices for which its log exists... not my case apparently) and after some research I found package matlib (function mpower) and package powerplus (function Matpow). Both accept non-integer powers but matlib has the restriction that the input matrix must be symmetric. So I ended up using Matpow from package powerplus and it did the trick. Hope it helps!